# How should I start a new iTerm terminal with shortcut?

Tags: macos, keyboard, automator, iterm

I've created a service in automator and assigned a shortcut, and it works.

[image]

But this doesn't start a new iTerm terminal. It only reveals the already running one

How can I start a new "tab" or a new "iTerm window"?

Answer (score 12):

You can change the Action in your Automator-defined service to an AppleScript action:

- Select Library/Run AppleScript in the Actions window
- Add the following AppleScript in the created Action and save:

```
if application "iTerm" is not running then
    activate application "iTerm"
else
    tell application "iTerm"
        create window with default profile
        activate
    end tell
end if
```

This opens iTerm if it is not running, else it opens a new window. See [iTerm documentation](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-scripting.html) for more examples of AppleScript scripting for iTerm.

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this with skhd.

`.skhdrc`:

```
ctrl + cmd - t : osascript /Users/user/Library/Scripts/new-iterm-window.scpt
```

`new-iterm-window.scpt`:

```
tell application "iTerm"
    create window with default profile
    activate
end tell
```

It is a bit faster than via standard services-shortcuts-menubar approach. It works literally in any app, even in one that doesn't have services menu or has that particular shortcut occupied, since skhd intercepts keys first.

Comment: This is the only answer that worked for me properly -- like you said it works from anywhere (unlike the Automator approach). Plus it's much neater to configure, no need to go through GUIs

Answer (score 4):

You can use iTerm keyboard shortcut:

- New Tab: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- New Window: <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

Comment: you have to focus the app for that. the question seems to ask for a global shortcut, not an application specific one.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an AppleScript that emulates human entry manually. In other words, drag and drop AppleScript and force the application to become the frontmost application and then invoke a contextual menu click as if you clicked it with your mouse. Then re-save it as your service.

And example, but not specific to your application would be:

```
activate application "ApplicationName"
tell application "System Events"
tell process "ApplicationName"
    keystroke "n" using {command down}
    delay 1
end tell
end tell
```